# Header file for function LockLibraryIntoProcessMem()

Tags: windows, dll, process

I have seen this function LockLibraryIntoProcessMem used to keep a Dll from unloading. What is the header file that defines thjis function ? I have searched MSDN and have found no mention of this function.

Comment: This is in the close queue but looks legit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an official windows API, thus, there is no MS header for this function.

Using a search engine I found a definition here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/vandooren/2006/10/09/preventing-a-dll-from-being-unloaded-by-the-app-that-uses-it/